# CMOS Output Sensor with a pull up resistor

Tags: pullup

The MH251 Hall Effect Switch has a CMOS output, which doesn't need a pull-up resistor. The typical application circuit on the datasheet is as shown: 
[image]
[image]

Since the same design will also be used by other sensors that require pull-up resistors. I am wondering if it is okay to add a pull-up resistor to the output of a CMOS Output sensor. What would be the difference between with and without a pull-up resistor?

[image]

Comment: I'd be a bit concerned about C2. When you switch states it becomes a momentary short-circuit for the CMOS switching transistors and a high current will flow on each transition.

Comment: @Transistor C2 is only 100pF and recommended by the datasheet.

Comment: That's all right then. There was no datasheet link so I didn't bother checking.

Comment: What Vcc are you using?

Comment: @Andyaka Vcc is 3.3v.

Comment: Pullup results in slight waste of power when output is low. You can avoid this by marking it DNP (Do Not Populate) on schematic for this chip and 10K on the open drain version.

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem with adding a pull-up resistor to the output as long as you don't exceed the current sinking capability of the CMOS driver.

The [MH251](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Magnesensor-Tech-MST-MH251EST_C114367.pdf) has a abs max output current of 1mA according to the datasheet, so your pull-up resistor must conduct less than this valu when Vcc is applied over it. For safety you want some margin, so lets say a max of 0.5mA. For a 3.3V supply, that gives \$R >> V/I=3.3V/0.5mA=6.6k\Omega\$. Something like a \$10k\Omega\$ pull-up should be fine.

---

Of course, even if you add the footprint for the pull-up resistor to the design, there is no requirement to populate it with a component.

When using the open-collector chip populate the footprint with the necessary resistor. Otherwise leave it unpopulated/DNI for the push-pull chip.

Comment: What happens when the push-pull chip output HIGH? What interaction will occur between the output signal and the pull-up resistor?

Comment: @RoastDuck The resistor is connected to VCC, and the output pulls up to Vcc. There will be no voltage across the resistor, so no current. The resisor will do nothing in that situation.

Comment: The sensor will be placed remotely from the MCU. The pull-up resistor will be placed on a PCB where the MCU is connected to. Will the voltage drop raise any concern?

Comment: @RoastDuck it shouldn't have any impact.